# Find Duplicates Based on Ranking

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, duplicates, numbers

A function that takes two parameters (array, ranking) and return an array.

The function should return the duplicated numbers based on ranking, for example:
if ranking parameter is 5, the function will return the 5 **most** duplicate numbers, even if there is 10 duplicated numbers, the function should only return the 5 most duplicated because ranking = 5.

I'm looking for efficient solution O(N) to solve this problem.

I know we could use hash map to count and then sort it then limit the returned array to "ranking" variable but this solution is not O(N).

Comment: Could you provide an example or two of an input array and the desired output? I'm a bit confused on what is meant by the `most duplicate numbers`. Also, I may be misunderstanding, but how does the function decide *which* N elements to return?

Comment: what're we dealing with here, files? database? both/other? what's the source?

Comment: the post to me, is unclear and possibly too broad. I'm out.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner You are not dealing with files or database, just variables stored in memory.

Comment: Ah; you know what? Strangely enough, that thought did enter my head earlier. Ok so it's a different ballgame that I thought it was. I figured that my "other" would have been answered and you did. I'd update your post to contain that, because of the "php" tag, that makes it code related and people usually expect to see attached code, which is what I expect to find since that is one of the tags that I follow. However, the fact remains that the question is too broad. If you're just looking for guidance, then that too would be broad a subject. Sorry, but I can only suggest searching on the web.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that you are going to be able to `count and then sort` in O(n).

Comment: The most expensive part there is trying to sort. That’s why I’m suggesting to just not sorting. If you still want to sort the whole hash map then you’ll be doing O(N²) or O(N * log N). If you use radix sort you would get average of kN. I’d rather use my approach as in a real case i don’t believe ranking would be dependent on N.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to sort. Once you counted all the repetitions you can just do one pass through the hash map and only keep the highest 5.

### Option 1

1. Iterate through the array filling the hash map, Key is the number, the value is the number of appearances. O(N)
2. Then you need an array the size of the ranking value(r). In here you will store the top numbers.
3. You then do one pass through the hash map O(N) and add the number to the array only if its number of appearances is higher than those of the less repeated number O(R). Here you can access the number of appearances by accessing the hash map using the values stored in the array as the key. This would be r direct accesses to the hash map for each entry in the hash map.
4. You have the top r number in the array.

O(N + RN) = O(RN)
(That's worst case. The pass of step 3 will be N only if there are no repeated numbers. If there are then it is less than N, but it doesn't matter)

### Option 2

Same as before but you do step 3 while doing step 1.
You skip the pass through the hash map on step three but will always do O(RN)

Comment: La Rosa: Could you please provide an example?

Usually hash maps are not sorted so if I take the first 5 elements it's not going to be the top 5.

Comment: I don't understand how  you conclude that `O(N + RN) == O(N)` in the worst case. Consider what this looks like as `N` grows if `R` is always `n-10`.

Comment: I is still linear. It is the same reason that N = KN = 2N = 34N = 2 +N.
You don't care about the constants and you only care about the most dominant terms

Comment: I take it back. Actually, I was referring to worst case scenario in regards to how long the hash map would be. Wasn't talking about R.
If R has a relation to N then you start having a whole different problem and could get close to N².

But for the original problem O(RN) would be correct

Comment: Yes, I think O(RN) makes more sense. Although R is not related to N, the worst case for R *is* related to N.